# Find elements with BeautifulSoup in a HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need to find all elements as `<td alert="0" op="0" class=" es_numero cell_imps24ad"><span>1.204</span></td>` in my html code. I can't send all the html code because it is confidential information.

I'm trying with this code:

```
# encoding=utf8
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import sys
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
lista = []
number = str(random.random())

user = ''
passwd = ''
url = ''
login = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, passwd))
url_sitios = ''

sitios = requests.get(url_sitios, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, passwd))
sitios2 = sitios.text
html = sitios2
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for item in soup.find_all("td", {"class": " es_numero cell_imps24ad"}):
    print item.text, item.next_sibling
```

And the output I want is something like this:
`es_numero cell_imps24ad : 1.204`

Comment: `soup.find_all("td", {"class": " es_numero cell_imps24ad"})` should be correct in this case. What output are you receiving instead of `es_numero cell_imps24ad : 1.204`?

Comment: I don´t receive nothing when I did it! So, I don't understand why I can't extract it. @Ajax1234

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the parse type to `BeautifulSoup`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml') #add the 'lxml' parser
for item in soup.find_all("td", {"class": " es_numero cell_imps24ad"}):
   print item.text, item.next_sibling
```

Edit: given the `nombre` and `url` tagged html, you can try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
s = "<url>https://www.google.com.ar/</url>\n<nombre>google.com.ar‌​</nombre>"
data = map(lambda x:x.text, soup(s, 'lxml').find_all(re.compile('nombre|url')))
```

Output:

```
[u'https://www.google.com.ar/', u'google.com.ar\u200c\u200b']
```

Edit 2: for smaller extractions:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
s = '<ultimas24hrs> <item id="imps24ad">0</item>'
new_s = soup(s, 'lxml')
the_id = int(new_s.find('item', {'id':"imps24ad"}).text)
```

Comment: I have the same results as before... `[]`

Comment: @MartinBouhier it is also possible that the website is dynamic i.e a script populates the page with the data once it is loaded. If that is the case, then you would have to use a browser manipulation tool such as `selenium`.

Comment: I solved with another url, xml instaed of html... the only question I need now is if I want to extract `nombre`and `url`, `for item in soup.find_all('nombre', 'url'):` did't work... how I need to do it?

Comment: What are `nombre` and `url`? The desired text, or tags and classes?

Comment: something like this: `<url>https://www.google.com.ar/</url>\n<nombre>google.com.ar</nombre>`, when I use `for item in soup.find_all( 'url'):`I have `https://www.google.com.ar` answer and when I use `nombre and url` I can´t extract both elements

Comment: `for item in soup.find_all(['nombre', 'url'])`this is the answer! Thanks!

Comment: @MartinBouhier glad to help! Also, I posted an additional solution to find `nombre` and `url`. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: I have this error with your form: `AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?` . `my xml starts with: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><html><body><lista><sitio sitio_id=`

Comment: if I need to extract only the number of `imps24ad`on: `<ultimas24hrs> <item id="imps24ad">0</item>\` how can I do it??

Comment: that is right but if you have 2 `imps24ad` it is not working